# Process Builder works only when the record is being edited,Initial Creation throws error

Tags: process-builder, approval-process, roll-up-summary

[image: Approval Process]
We have a process builder which auto approves a quote based on a specific approval process with a criteria defined as **discountpercent__c > 2**.Wherein the field **discountpercent__c** is a rollup summary field and sums it up  based on  discount field in quote.
Now the problem is that the quote gets auto approved only when it is  edited.If we try creating a new record it throws the following error

> > Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow The record couldn’t be saved
> >     because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute
> >     the flow with version ID 30136000000DWbb. Contact your administrator
> >     for help.
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.

But manually submitting the record works fine.Any idea on why Process builder causes such error???

Updated Error:

> This report lists the elements that the flow interview executed. The
>   report is a beta feature. We welcome your feedback on IdeaExchange.
>
> Flow Details Flow Name: Quote_Approval Type: Workflow Version: 1
>   Status: Active
>
> Flow Interview Details Interview Label: Quote_Approval-1_Quote Current
>   User: Baku A (00536000002df2q) Start time: 7/28/2016 2:16 AM Duration:
>   0 seconds
>
> How the Interview Started Baku A (00536000002df2q) started the flow
>   interview. Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview
>   started. myVariable_old = null myVariable_current = 0Q036000000AYlnCAG
>
> ASSIGNMENT: myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment
>   {!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} Equals {!Flow.CurrentDateTime}
>   Result {!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} = "7/28/2016 2:16 AM"
>
> DECISION: myDecision Executed this outcome: myRule_1 Outcome
>   conditions: and
>   1. {!formula_myRule_1} (true) Equals true Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)
>
> SUBMIT FOR APPROVAL: myRule_1_A1 Inputs: objectId =
>   {!myVariable_current.Id} (0Q036000000AYlnCAG) comment = null
>   processDefinitionNameOrId = Quote_Approval skipEntryCriteria = false
>
> Error Occurred: No applicable approval process was found.

Comment: Can you paste your debug logs during this.  It would tell us exactly at which component in the process builder, the flow failed.  Also, an email would have been sent (to the last modified by user of the process builder) with the error details.  Please review.

Comment: I have updated my question @sfdcFanBoy

Answer (score 1):

Since the discountpercent__c is a roll-up summary. At creation your record won't have a value (you can't have children before you insert a record as you need it's Id).

What is happening is that you flow is calling the approval process, but the record does not pass the entry criteria and hence the error you found.

A way to avoid that is to make sure the entry criteria for your flow is the same as the Approval Process.

Comment: From the debug logs - Error Occurred: No applicable approval process was found.

Comment: Exatcly. That means that the record didn't match the criteria for the approval process.,

Comment: THanks @Fernando Gavinho,  Do you mean the criteria defined for process builder should be the same as approval process entry criteria?

Comment: yes. That's exactly what I mean. =D

Comment: Tried adding it.But now process builder doesn't  seem to work.I mean we had to manually go and approve it .

Answer (score 0):

> This error is thrown when an object is attempted to be submitted for
>   approval either because
>
> 1. The approval process isn't activated
> 2. OR your object doesn't meet the entry criteria.
> 3. OR If you have selected Let the submitter choose the approver manually option under step-3 (select assigned approver ) in your
>      approval process, then Process builder won’t work.

[image]

Can you confirm the 3 points mentioned are fine in your case.

1. Yours is active from your screenshot.  Okay (y)
2. Make sure the conditions in your decision box in the process builder are the same as entry criteria i.e., the process builder should call the Approval Process only when `DiscountPercent!=null && DiscountPercent>2`.
3. Make sure an approver is assigned directly in the approval process (not manual)

Comment: Thanks @ sfdcFanBoy, I tried adding the entry  criteria as you specified still the error persist.

Comment: I have added the screen shots of the Approval Process for your reference

Comment: Updated answer.